# EntitySqlException on CreateQuery and type mismatch

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, exception

I have this situation. I call `CreateQuery` with this query and I get Exception.

```
string sql = "SELECT VALUE CP 
                FROM CIC_PRODUZIONE_OPERAZIONI_View AS CP 
                WHERE  CP.CD_PLANT = 5 
                   AND CP.CD_POSTI = 10946 
                   AND (CP.FL_STATE IN {N'D',N'N',N'M'}) 
                   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                               FROM CIC_OPERAZIONI AS C 
                               WHERE CP.CD_CIC_PRODUZIONE = C.CD_CIC_PRODUZIONE 
                                  AND C.CD_POSTI = 10894 
                                  AND C.AFCDOPER = (SELECT VALUE TOP (1) D.AFCDOPER                                                                     FROM CIC_OPERAZIONI AS D
    WHERE D.CD_CIC_PRODUZIONE = CP.CD_CIC_PRODUZIONE 
      AND D.AFCDOPER > CP.AFCDOPER 
    ORDER BY D.AFCDOPER)) 
    ORDER BY CP.AFCDPROD, CP.FL_STATE, CP.AFESPSAP, CP.AFESPMOD, CP.AFCDOPER";

    ObjectQuery<T> entities = CreateQuery<T>(sql);
```

This is the Exception:

> EntitySqlException: The argument types 'Edm.Decimal' and
>   'Transient.collection[Edm.Decimal(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=4,Scale=0)]'
>   are incompatible for this operation.

The problem seems to be when I try to select the `TOP` value.

Any suggestion?

**EDIT**

I undestand that the problem is on the right side of the expression because the subquery get an `ICollection<decimal>` and on the left I have a decimal field.

...

```
C.AFCDOPER = (SELECT VALUE TOP (1) D.AFCDOPER                                                                     FROM CIC_OPERAZIONI AS D
        WHERE D.CD_CIC_PRODUZIONE = CP.CD_CIC_PRODUZIONE 
          AND D.AFCDOPER > CP.AFCDOPER
```

...

how could it be possible to get the "First" of that collection to avoid to get in exception?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to compare a `decimal` property to a `ICollection<decimal>` property but it's impossible to tell without knowing more about your model.

Comment: The field AFCDOPER is a Decimal(4, 0) on DB. In my Model.edmx is a decimal

Comment: The question is at this point: How could I select the first element of the ICollection<decimal>?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ?

```
Select Top(1) D.AFCDOPER   FROM CIC_OPERAZIONI AS D
```

I think this will work without the world "VALUE" .

Comment: No. Unfortunately I got the same Exception

Comment: could u five us your schema??
so I can try??

Comment: I think I understand the problem.
The subquery returns an ICollection<decimal> and in left side I have a decimal.
At this point I have to find how to rewrite that query

Comment: Ok ...
Good Job
Best Regards